# Delete user files

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created a script to delete the files of the users within the assigned path.

I'd like to unify the variables so I don't make it too long.

```
$folder = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\*"
$folder2 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\*"
$folder3 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\*"
$folder4 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Contacts\*"
$folder5 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Downloads\*"
$folder6 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Favorites\*"
$folder7 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\links\*"
$folder8 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Music\*"
$folder9 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\OneDrive\*"
$folder10 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Pictures\*"
$folder11 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Searches\*"
$folder12 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Videos\*"


If (Test-Path $folder) {
    Remove-Item $folder -Exclude AppData,Contacts,Desktop,Documents,Downloads,Favorites,Links,Music,OneDrive,Pictures,Searches,Videos -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder2 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder3 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder4 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder5 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder6 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder7 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder8 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder9 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder10 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder11 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder12 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I've tried the following way and it doesn't work:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\*"
$folder2 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\*"
$folder3 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\*"
$folder4 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Contacts\*"
$folder5 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Downloads\*"
$folder6 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Favorites\*"
$folder7 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\links\*"
$folder8 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Music\*"
$folder9 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\OneDrive\*"
$folder10 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Pictures\*"
$folder11 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Searches\*"
$folder12 = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Videos\*"


If (Test-Path $folder) {
    Remove-Item $folder -Exclude AppData,Contacts,Desktop,Documents,Downloads,Favorites,Links,Music,OneDrive,Pictures,Searches,Videos -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Remove-Item $folder2 + $folder3 + $folder4 + $folder5 + $folder6 + $folder7 + $folder8 + $folder9 + $folder10 + $folder11 + $folder12 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I would also like to get a log of what has been done, for example, if files or folders were found within the paths.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Path` parameter of `Remove-Item` accepts a string array as input, if you want to remove more than one item at once.

Now with the syntax `$folder2 + $folder3` you are creating a concatenated string like: `"C:\Users\foo\Desktop\*C:\Users\foo\Desktop\*""`. That is nothing that `Remove-Item` can handle.

You can build a string array of paths like this:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME"
$foldersToRemove = @(
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Contacts",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Downloads",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Favorites",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\links",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Music",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\OneDrive",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Pictures",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Searches",
    "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Videos")

    If (Test-Path $folder) {
        Remove-Item $folder -Exclude AppData, Contacts, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Links, Music, OneDrive, Pictures, Searches, Videos -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-Item $foldersToRemove -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

---

About your second requirement:

The `-Verbose` parameter will make `Remove-Item` tell you, which folders are removed. If you need your log in a file, you can redirect the verbose stream like this:

```
Remove-Item $foldersToRemove -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose 4> .\deletedFolders.log
```